# Extracting a p-value from a test in R

Tags: r, knitr

I cannot seem to be able to extract a specific value from my code

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(50),
                  x2 = 2*rnorm(50),
                  x3 = 3*runif(50)) 

shapiro.test(df$x1)
```

After this chunk, there's an output in the R-studio pane where I get a p-value in which I want to extract to my output file.

So my question is how I easily can extract that p-value using inline R-code.

Comment: Assign the result to a variable: `p <- shapiro.test(df$x1)`. Get the p-value like so: `p$p.value`.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy:

```
shapiro.test(df$x1)$p
[1] 0.6798121
```

Comment: Ok, and how will I be able to extract this value in my HTML. document so that I can do a cross-reference to it?

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(50),
                 x2 = 2*rnorm(50),
                 x3 = 3*runif(50)) 

test<-shapiro.test(df$x1)
test$p.value
```

Answer (score 0):

First store your value inside your chunk

```
pvalue <- shapiro.test(df$x1)$p.value
```

Then write outside of the chunk

```
`r paste(pvalue)`
```

This will display your pvalue when you knit.
It is interesting because if your outcome changes, the text will also change.

If you need more cross-referencing:
https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/cross-ref.html

Comment: This is what I needed with r line code. Thank you!